# anaconda install of RStudio prompts for admin on windows

Tags: anaconda, rstudio, conda, miniconda

I am looking to deploy anaconda to allow users to manage their own RStudio and Python environments on computers they do not have admin permissions on. I am hitting an issue where users are hit with an admin prompt when installing RStudio either from Navigator or command line.

- Miniconda
- All user install
- platform : win-64
- user-agent : conda/4.5.12 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.1 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.16299

I started by attempting an install from Navigator, it errored and failed. Wanting more information, I switched to command line and attempted it from there:

```
conda create --name rstudio
conda activate rstudio
conda install rstudio
```

This results in the downloads followed by:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: - 
DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(196): Menu: name: 'RStudio Desktop ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\jeff\.conda\env\rstudio', env_name: 'rstudio', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is "C:\Program Files\conda\python.exe", args are ['"C:\\Program Files\\conda\\cwp.py"', 'C:\\Users\\jeff\\.conda\\env\\rstudio', 'C:\\Users\\jeff\\.conda\\env\\rstudio\\Library\\bin\\rstudio.exe']
done
```

Just before the `DEBUG` message appears, I'm hit with an admin prompt. It appears that the install works, even if I cancel the admin prompt (I just get the error message)

The biggest issue is that the admin prompt is scaring people. Secondarily, it (appears) to be preventing the feature from becoming active in Navigator.

Is there a way to prevent the admin prompt?

Comment: I would suggest not installing conda into Program Files. Probably the reason for the prompt is because conda is trying to add start menu shortcuts for all users, which requires permission

Comment: Why not program files? Space in name?

Comment: Because any changes to that folder require administrator permission, although I see now that all the envs are going in a user folder. Did you install for "All Users" when you installed Anaconda? That might make installing Start Menu shortcuts default to all users, although doing that for packages only installed in user environments would be strange. Hmm...

Comment: Yes, its an "all users" install. It's easier to work with the organisation's central software deployment system. Life is easier if the install-o-bot has no information about which user it is installing for.